# Ionic : Navigate in nested states breaks history and ion-nav-back-button

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

It seems impossible to navigate to a child state of a sibling or to a child state of an ancestor.

The workaround I used was to put all the states on the same level, which allows me to navigate to any state I need (navigate from a push notification to a nested state, navigate from one nested state to a state inside another parent, etc ...).

The problem with that method is that states and controllers do not inherit any code, leading to code duplication. Moreover, there are cases where the navigation is simply broken and the ion-nav-back-button do not behave as it should.

**TLTR: What structure must be used to have a fully navigable application (check out the pen), when you use tabs and nested states ?**

Here is the pen describing the problem : http://codepen.io/ruslan-fidesio/pen/LkyAkm

HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="app">
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

        <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="Home">
                <ion-content>
                    <br/>
                    <a ui-sref="app.tabs.themes.details">Go to Child : broken</a>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <a ui-sref="app.other">Go to Other : broken</a>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
        </script>

        <script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                <ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
                <ion-tab title="home" ui-sref="app.tabs.home">
                    <ion-nav-view name="tabs-home"></ion-nav-view>
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab title="themes" ui-sref="app.tabs.themes.list">
                    <ion-nav-view name="tabs-themes"></ion-nav-view>
                </ion-tab>
            </ion-tabs>
        </script>

        <script id="themes/abstract.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-dark" sticky>
                Themes subheader
            </div>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </script>

        <script id="themes/list.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="Themes">
                <ion-content class="has-subheader">
                    <p>Parent View</p>
                    <a ui-sref="app.tabs.themes.details">Go to Child : OK !</a>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
        </script>

        <script id="themes/details.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="Theme X">
                <ion-content class="has-subheader">
                    Child View
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
        </script>

        <script id="other.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-view view-title="Other">
                <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                    <ion-nav-back-button>
                    </ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-content>
                    <br/>
                    Other View
                    <br/>
                    <a ui-sref="app.tabs.themes.details">Go to Child : broken</a>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module(
    'app', [
        'ionic'
    ]
);

app.run(
    function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(
            function() {
                if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
                }

                if (window.StatusBar) {
                    StatusBar.styleDefault();
                }
            }
        );
    }
);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
        })
        .state('app.tabs', {
            url: '/tabs',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
        })
        .state('app.tabs.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'tabs-home': {
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.other', {
            url: '/other',
            templateUrl: 'other.html'
        })
        .state('app.tabs.themes', {
            url: '/themes',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'tabs-themes': {
                    templateUrl: 'themes/abstract.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.tabs.themes.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'themes/list.html'
        })
        .state('app.tabs.themes.details', {
            url: '/details',
            templateUrl: 'themes/details.html'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs/home');
});

app.config(
    ['$ionicConfigProvider', function($ionicConfigProvider) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
        $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it is related to IonTabs and separated ion-nav-views.
(check out this picture : http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png )

In this case, it is better to replace tabs with custom "tabs" implementation using only one ion-nav-view as shown here : http://codepen.io/ruslan-fidesio/pen/RRgpjL

HTML :

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
<better-tabs style="positive">
    <better-tab state="app.tabs.home" title="Home"></better-tab>
  <better-tab state="app.tabs.themes.list" root-state="app.tabs.themes" title="Themes"></better-tab>
</better-tabs>
```

JS :

```
app.directive(
'betterTabs',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        var footer = angular.element('<ion-footer-bar></ion-footer-bar>');
        var tabs = elem.find('better-tab');
        elem.append(footer);
        footer.append(tabs);

        if (attrs.style) {
          footer.addClass('bar-' + attrs.style);
        }
      }
    };
  }
);
app.directive(
  'betterTab',
  ['$state', function($state) {
    return {
      scope: {
        state: '@',
        rootState: '@',
        title: '@'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      required: ['^betterTabs'],
      link: function(scope) {
       scope.$state = $state;
      },
      template: function() {
        return '<a ui-sref="{{ state }}" ng-class="{active: $state.includes(\'{{ rootState ? rootState : state }}\')}">{{ title }}</a>';
      }
    };
  }]
);
```